# Filter c# Object list with query string

Tags: c#, list, parsing

I am developing a C# MVC project and I have a list of objects as:

```
var list = [{
            ID: 100,
            PRODUCTNO: 500,
            PARAMETER: TEST0,
            VALUE: 120
            },
            {
            ID:101,
            PRODUCTNO:501,
            PARAMETER:TEST1,
            VALUE:121
            },
            {
            ID:102,
            PRODUCTNO:502,
            PARAMETER:TEST2,
            VALUE:122
            },
            {
            ID:103,
            PRODUCTNO:503,
            PARAMETER:TEST3,
            VALUE:123
            }]
```

I need to filter data from this list by using a query string like:

```
"((PRODUCTNO==502 && VALUE>121)||(PARAMETER=='TEST3' && VALUE<=(56x3.14)))"
```

I can't use LINQ and I can only use query as a string.

Is there any way to do this? Any plugins or something?

Comment: Any effort from your side to achieve this?

Comment: Actually I don't know where to start. I have just the list and a query string.

Comment: https://www.linkedin.com/learning/c-sharp-essential-training

Answer (score 1):

Effectively what you have here is a Domain-Specific Language.  What you *need* is a parser for it.

You can build one yourself.  There are a number of tutorials and discussions available online that would be useful.  Searches for `domain specific language` and `recursive descent parser` ([this article](http://blog.roboblob.com/2014/12/12/introduction-to-recursive-descent-parsers-with-csharp/) for instance) and so on would be helpful if you want to go down this route.

If you don't have the patience or the inclination to learn how to write your own language from scratch there are plenty of libraries and frameworks out there for building  There are a couple of ways to go about it.  Something like [Nitra](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/Nitra/Home) or [Sprache](https://github.com/sprache/sprache) for instance might be useful.

Since you want to allow calculations like `VALUE<=(56x3.14)` in your query it might be useful to start with [Sprach.Calc](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/795056/Sprache-Calc-building-yet-another-expression-evalu).